# forwardfill combined with calculation (method='ffill' * xyz) in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I need to fill NaN spaces with a calculation, that depends on the previous values in the dataframe = df. What I have so far is this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 6, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 8]})
df["c"] =np.NaN

df["c"][0] = 1
df["c"][2] = 3

i = 1
while i<10:
    df.c.fillna(df.c.shift(i)*df.b,inplace=True)
    i+1
```

Unfortunately the solution with this while loop does not work and is certainly a very bad solution for pandas. So what I am looking for is kind of a

```
df.c.fillna(method='ffill'*df.b,inplace=True)
```

I know that also doesn't work, I just think that makes it clearer what I am looking for.

Before filling the dataframe it looks like this:

```
   b   c
0  2   1
1  3 NaN
2 10   3
3  3 NaN
4  5 NaN
5  8 NaN
```

The desired outcome should look like this:

```
      b   c
0     2   1  # nothing filled in since data is set from df["c"][0] = 1
1     3   3  # fill in previous c * b = 1 * 3 = 3
2    10   3  # nothing filled in since data is set from df["c"][2] = 3
3     3   9  # fill in previous c * b = 3 * 3 = 9
4     5  45  # fill in previous c * b = 9 * 5 = 45
5     8 360  # fill in previous c * b = 45 * 8 = 360
```

So basically: if there is no data availabe, it should be filled with a caculation.

Comment: Can you post what the desired df looks like so it's clearer as your loop does something different to what you expect the one liner does

Comment: @EdChum: I just added the desired outcome, hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't figure out a way to do this in a single loop, the problem here is that you want some kind of rolling apply that can then look at the previous row, the problem here is that the previous row update will not be observable until the `apply` finishes so for instance the following works because we in run the apply 3 times. This isn't great IMO:

```
In [103]:
def func(x):
    if pd.notnull(x['c']):
        return x['c']
    else:
        return df.iloc[x.name - 1]['c'] * x['b']
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df

Out[103]:
      a   b    c
0  None   2    1
1  None   3    3
2  None  10    3
3  None   3    9
4  None   5   45
5  None   8  360
```

Comment: Great that works! But if I want to implement that in a dataframe where the index is in the datetime format, it returns: `ValueError: ('Cannot add integral value to Timestamp without offset.', u'occurred at index 1999-01-04 00:00:00') `
What's the matter here?

Comment: @hb.klein not sure what you mean by your comment if you have another  different question then you should post another question

Comment: Ok, I posted another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30676186/python-datetimeindex-error-typeerror-cannot-do-label-indexing-on-class-pa