# Automating fill with calculation function in python

Tags: python, pandas

What I got so far is the code below and it works fine and brings the results it should: It fills `df['c']` with the calculation `previous c * b` if there is no `c` given. The problem is that I have to apply this to a bigger data set `len(df.index) = ca. 10.000`, so the function I have so far is inappropriate since I would have to write a couple of thousand times: `df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)`. A `while` loop is no option in `pandas` for this size of dataset. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

randn = np.random.randn
rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 10, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 6]},index=rng)
df["c"] =np.NaN

df["c"][0] = 1
df["c"][2] = 3


def func(x):
    if pd.notnull(x['c']):
        return x['c']
    else:
        return df.iloc[df.index.get_loc(x.name) - 1]['c'] * x['b']

df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
```

Comment: The solution I am applying I foud here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641509/forwardfill-combined-with-calculation-method-ffill-xyz-in-python-pandas

Comment: @boardrider What do you think is the problem with this question?

Comment: @hb.klein Your edit does not make this question the least bit more searchable. The tags "python" and "pandas" are already on this post, which is how I and everyone else will find it. Also, Stack Overflow already prepends the tag to every page title so Google will handle it better.

Comment: Difficult to get a clear idea what your issue really is. 

Try to re-formulate as: I want to do A, I tried B,C, and D, Here's a minimal code E that demonstrate my problem, and here're the exceptions I'm getting on input F or G.

Comment: @boardrider This questions makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: Power to you, @chrisaycock :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice way of solving a recurrence problem. There will be docs on this in v0.16.2 (releasing next week). See docs for [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/)

This will be quite performant as the real heavy lifting is done in fast jit-ted compiled code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.nan * 10, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 6]},index=rng)
df.ix[0,"c"] = 1
df.ix[2,"c"] = 3

@jit
def ffill(arr_b, arr_c):

    n = len(arr_b)
    assert len(arr_b) == len(arr_c)
    result = arr_c.copy()

    for i in range(1,n):
        if not np.isnan(arr_c[i]):
            result[i] = arr_c[i]
        else:
            result[i] = result[i-1]*arr_b[i]

    return result

df['d'] = ffill(df.b.values, df.c.values)

             a   b   c      d
2011-01-01 NaN   2   1      1
2011-01-02 NaN   3 NaN      3
2011-01-03 NaN  10   3      3
2011-01-04 NaN   3 NaN      9
2011-01-05 NaN   5 NaN     45
2011-01-06 NaN   8 NaN    360
2011-01-07 NaN   4 NaN   1440
2011-01-08 NaN   1 NaN   1440
2011-01-09 NaN   2 NaN   2880
2011-01-10 NaN   6 NaN  17280
```

Comment: Could you kindly look at this question, it's quite similar. We just can't find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745160/portfolio-rebalancing-with-bandwidth-method-in-python

Answer (score 4):

If you print out the values of `df` in a for-loop:

```
for i in range(7):
    df['c'] = df.apply(func, axis =1)
    print(df)
```

you can trace the origin of the values in the `c` column:

```
               a   b      c
2011-01-01  None   2      1    1
2011-01-02  None   3      3    3*1
2011-01-03  None  10      3    1*3*1
2011-01-04  None   3      9    3*1*3*1
2011-01-05  None   5     45    5*3*1*3*1
2011-01-06  None   8    360    ...
2011-01-07  None   4   1440    ...
2011-01-08  None   1   1440    ...
2011-01-09  None   2   2880    ...
2011-01-10  None   6  17280    6*2*4*8*5*3*3
```

You can clearly see the values are coming from a cumulative product.
Each row is the value from the previous row multiplied by some new number.
That new number sometimes comes from `b`, or is sometimes a 1 (when `c` is not NaN).

So if we can create a column `d` which has these "new" numbers in it, then the desired values can be computed by the `cumprod`:

```
df['c'] = df['d'].cumprod()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

randn = np.random.randn

def setup_df():
    rng = pd.date_range('1/1/2011', periods=10, freq='D')
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [None] * 10, 'b': [2, 3, 10, 3, 5, 8, 4, 1, 2, 6]},
                      index=rng)
    df["c"] = np.NaN
    df.iloc[0, -1] = 1
    df.iloc[2, -1] = 3
    return df

df = setup_df()
df['d'] = df['b']
mask = pd.notnull(df['c'])
df.loc[mask, 'd'] = 1
df['c'] = df['d'].cumprod()
print(df)
```

yields

```
               a   b      c  d
2011-01-01  None   2      1  1
2011-01-02  None   3      3  3
2011-01-03  None  10      3  1
2011-01-04  None   3      9  3
2011-01-05  None   5     45  5
2011-01-06  None   8    360  8
2011-01-07  None   4   1440  4
2011-01-08  None   1   1440  1
2011-01-09  None   2   2880  2
2011-01-10  None   6  17280  6
```

I left the `d` column in to help show where the `c` values are coming from.
You can of course delete the column with

```
del df['d']
```

Or better yet, as chrisaycock points out, you could forgo defining the `d`
column altogether and instead use

```
df['c'] = np.where(pd.notnull(df['c']), 1, df['b']).cumprod()
```

Comment: This is very nice and should be accepted as the answer. If the OP wants a one-liner, it's simply `np.where(pd.notnull(df.c), 1, df.b).cumprod()`.

Comment: Thanks; that's a nicer way to express it.

Comment: Could you kindly look at this question, it's quite similar. We just can't find a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745160/portfolio-rebalancing-with-bandwidth-method-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can just write a write loop like this:

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if pd.isnull(df.c[i]):
        df.c[i] = df.c[i-1] * df.b[i]
```

If this takes too long for you, you could `jit` it with numba. Your example DataFrame is too small for a meaningful test on my system though.

Comment: hah, see my example...already done! note you cannot directly jit the way you have written it though. You cannot use things like ``pd.isnull``, nor the indexing operators; you have to use numpy arrays (and then wrap then at the end).

Comment: @Jeff Ah, that makes sense. My test of jit actually came-out slower than vanilla Python, but I had thought that was just an issue of how small the DataFrame was. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: yes, it *would* work, but it will be in *python* mode (hence its not really translating to LLVM, etc.); you can force *nopython* mode, e.g. ``jit(nopython=True)`` to force it to raise if you do something that is not kosher :)

Comment: @chrisaycock : could you kindly have a look at this. Its a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745160/portfolio-rebalancing-with-bandwidth-method-in-python